# Getting error while using file.read() function with encoding command

Tags: python

```
file = open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") 
text = file.read()
print(file)
```

And there is an utf-8 character in my text.

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Main\PycharmProjects\Python\file-reading.py", line 2, in <module>
    text = file.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^   
File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position16: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried to use `.read()`, but it doesn't works.

Comment: The file isn't encoded in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Side note: consider using [`open` with a `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) or using [`Path.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) to avoid needing to manually manage the open file resource.

Comment: `0xdd` is `Ý` in [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). If that looks like the character you'd expect at position 16, try using `encoding="cp1252"`.

Comment: Relevant obligatory background reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, the file you're trying to read is not in `utf-8 format`. Also as best practice, you should use the `with` statement so that your file will be closed automatically after reading it. Else, you'd have to write extra code to close your file.

```
with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_object:
    text = file_object.read()
    print(file_object)
```

You can check that the file is closed by using `file_object.closed` which will return `True` in this case.